# Simple DBIx::Class query with DISTINCT and WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, dbix-class

My table, speakers:

```
id | type | speaker | updated_on
```

The MySQL query I'm trying to replicate in DBIx::Class is:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT speaker FROM speakers WHERE type = "motivational"
```

The following is returning all records in the table and should only be returning 5 (there are only 5 distinct speakers):

```
my $speakers = $schema->resultset('Speakers')->search (
    { type => 'motivational'},
    { select => [{ distinct => 'speaker' }] }      
);
```

Trying to get my head around some of the nuances of DBIx::Class, and am stuck on this one. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Reread the docs, your select syntax is incorrect.
You're looking for a combination of columns (combined select + as which is preferred over select) plus distinct.